# Is there any difference on installing TypeScript from Web Essentials and separately?

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

Is the version of TypeScript on Web Essentials the same as the one provided by the TypeScript web site?

http://vswebessentials.com/features/typescript

Here is the link provided by the TypeScript web site:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=266563

Is there any differences between them?

Comment: The Web Essentials site tells you you need the second plugin as well. WE extends it with new features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the two. In fact web essentials leads to the same url. ie:

http://vswebessentials.com/features/typescript > http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download > "Download the plugin" > http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

Whic is same as > 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=266563 > http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

I prefer to download from https://typescript.codeplex.com/releases/ Since you get the even more cutting edge versions as well (e.g. you can get 0.9.0). But no difference between old versions (e.g. 0.8.3 are same at codeplex as MS site)

Comment: Actually the Web Essentials depends on the download provided by the typescript website: "Full support for TypeScript preview and compilation. Remember to install the official plug-in for Visual Studio to take full advantage of TypeScript"

Comment: @Vinicius Yup. Which is the path I mentioned "Download the plugin" is the link to the official vs plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Web Essentials depends on the download provided by the typescript website:

> "Full support for TypeScript preview and compilation. Remember to install the official plug-in for Visual Studio to take full advantage of TypeScript"